# Как мне задать ротацию для спавнящихся платформ?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
        using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawnplatforms : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platform;
    private GameObject platforminst;
    private Vector3 platformpos;
    private float speed = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        platformpos = new Vector3 (Random.Range(0.93f, 1.74f), Random.Range (2.18f,-3.36f),0f);
        platforminst = Instantiate(platform, new Vector3(5f, -6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        platforminst.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(1.2f, 2f) , platforminst.transform.localScale.y, platforminst.transform.localScale.z);
platform.transform.localRotation = //*Как мне задать ротацию для спавнящихся платформ?*
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (platforminst.transform.position != platformpos)
            platforminst.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(platforminst.transform.position, platformpos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо `Quaternion.identity` передавайте какой вам нужен поворот.

Comment: На -45 градусов по Y

Comment: То есть мне нужно чтобы платформа спавнилась именно под таким углом

Comment: зачем два раза [одно и то же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1064147/179763) спрашивать?

Comment: Потому что никето не отвечает

Comment: @Lemon124 врёшь.

Answer (score 0):

`platform.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);`.

Указывается непосредственно в градусах.

Comment: Каким знаком написать градусы?  °?

Comment: Знаки? Facepalm...

Comment: Просто так или с пeременной f код не срабатывает

Comment: С преминением `Vector3` так, как вы его и преминяете.

Comment: platform.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, -45f, 0f);?