# Как мне задать ротацию для спавнящихся платформ(мне нужно чтобы платформа спавнилась под углом в -45 градусов по Y)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Spawnplatforms : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject platform;
        private GameObject platforminst;
        private Vector3 platformpos;
        private float speed = 5f;

        void Start()
        {
            platformpos = new Vector3 (Random.Range(0.93f, 1.74f), Random.Range (2.18f,-3.36f),0f);
            platforminst = Instantiate(platform, new Vector3(5f, -6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            platforminst.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(1.2f, 2f) , platforminst.transform.localScale.y, platforminst.transform.localScale.z);
            platform.transform.localRotation = //*Как мне задать ротацию для спавнящихся платформ?*
        }
        void Update()
        {
            if (platforminst.transform.position != platformpos)
                platforminst.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(platforminst.transform.position, platformpos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
```