# Как мне задать ротацию для платформ(платформа не вращается)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Spawnplatforms : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject platform;
        private GameObject platforminst;
        private Vector3 platformpos;
        private float speed = 5f;

        void Start()
        {
            platformpos = new Vector3 (Random.Range(0.93f, 1.74f), Random.Range (2.18f,-3.36f),0f);
            platforminst = Instantiate(platform, new Vector3(5f, -6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            platforminst.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(1.2f, 2f) , platforminst.transform.localScale.y, platforminst.transform.localScale.z);
            platform.transform.localRotation = //*Как мне задать ротацию для спавнящихся платформ???(платформа должна появиться под углом в -45 градусов по Y)*
        }
        void Update()
        {
            if (platforminst.transform.position != platformpos)
                platforminst.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(platforminst.transform.position, platformpos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064118/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc) раза...